# Como vincular models (com association), forms e grids no ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs-4

Estou utilizando ExtJS 4.2 em um projeto e estou com problemas envolvendo as associations do model e como vinculá-las à forms e grids. Vou ilustrar com um exemplo.

Tenho 3 classes e 1 json, como seguem abaixo:

**Usuario**

```
Ext.define('Usuario', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'nome'],

    hasMany: { model: 'Telefone', name: 'telefones' }
    hasOne: { model: 'Endereco', name: 'endereco'}
});
```

**Endereco**

```
Ext.define('Endereco', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'logradouro', 'endereco', 'numero', 'cidade', 'estado', 'usuario_id']
});
```

**Telefone**

```
Ext.define('Telefone', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'ddd', 'numero', 'usuario_id'],
});
```

**Json *usuarios***

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Maria",
            "telefones": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "ddd": 11,
                    "numero": 33445566
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "ddd": 12,
                    "numero": 988887777
                }
            ],
            "endereco": {
                "id": 1,
                "logradouro": "Rua",
                "endereco": "Santa Rosa",
                "numero": 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

O problema começou quando precisei salvar dados aninhados. Aí encontrei no [blog da Loiane Groner uma postagem sobre salvar dados aninhados](http://www.loiane.com/2013/11/ext-js-4-salvar-modelstore-que-tenha-associations-hasmany-e-hasone/).
Funcionou! Aí veio outro problema, maior: como vincular um model com associations a um form e grid? E depois, como salvar o dado do form utilizando o model e seu proxy já configurado?

Vi que muita gente faz no próprio form um submit com a url e proxy a ser usado, mas se utilizando MVC eu já criei meu model, store e proxy, porque devo montar novamente o proxy no form e ignorar a minha estrutura já feita? Gostaria de utilizar os recursos que implementei no model, store e proxy...

Bem, [encontrei um texto que mostra como fazer o vínculo (no caso de form)](http://moduscreate.com/expert-ext-js-associations-in-forms/), porém estou com dificuldades para entender a solução dele e parece que não funciona para model com associação hasOne.

Comment: Sua pergunta fez sucesso mas parece que você vai ter que convidar colegas que usam o ExtJS para poder respondê-las. O que é incentivado fazer mesmo.

Comment: É, então, problema que ninguém sabe responder essa, rs.

Comment: Mas vou trazer mais gente pra cá, sim.

Comment: Eu posso tentar te ajudar, mas gostaria que você explicasse o que exatamente você gostaria de fazer, para que eu consiga entender o contexto e assim entender por completo seu problema.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode montar uma grid usando `renderer` da `columns`.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Usuários',
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Nome',
        dataIndex: 'nome'
    },{
        text: 'Telefones',
        renderer: function (val, meta, record) {
            var tel = '';
            record.telefones().each(function(telRecord, index, count) {
                if(tel.length>0) tel = tel + '; '
                tel = tel + '(' + telRecord.get('ddd') + ') ' + telRecord.get('numero');
            });
            return tel;
        }
    },{
        text: 'Endereço',
        renderer: function (val, meta, record) {
            var obj = record.getEndereco().data;
            var enderecos = '';
            enderecos = enderecos + obj.logradouro;
            enderecos = enderecos + ' ' + obj.endereco;
            enderecos = enderecos + ' ' + obj.numero;
            enderecos = enderecos + ' - ' + obj.cidade;
            return enderecos;
        }
    }

             ],
    height: 200,
    width: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Exemplo ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mXzMj/2/)):

```js
Ext.define('Usuario', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'nome'],

    hasMany: { model: 'Telefone', name: 'telefones' },
    hasOne: { model: 'Endereco', name: 'endereco'}
});

Ext.define('Endereco', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'logradouro', 'endereco', 'numero', 'cidade', 'estado', 'usuario_id']
});

Ext.define('Telefone', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'ddd', 'numero', 'usuario_id']
});


var data = {
    "success": "true",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Maria",
            "telefones": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "ddd": 11,
                    "numero": 33445566
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "ddd": 12,
                    "numero": 988887777
                }
            ],
            "endereco": {
                "id": 1,
                "logradouro": "Rua",
                "endereco": "Santa Rosa",
                "numero": 6
            }
        }
    ]
};

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: "Usuario",
    autoLoad: true,
    data: data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Usuários',
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Nome',
        dataIndex: 'nome'
    },{
        text: 'Telefones',
        renderer: function (val, meta, record) {
            var tel = '';
            record.telefones().each(function(telRecord, index, count) {
                if(tel.length>0) tel = tel + '; '
                tel = tel + '(' + telRecord.get('ddd') + ') ' + telRecord.get('numero');
            });
            return tel;
        }
    },{
        text: 'Endereço',
        renderer: function (val, meta, record) {
            var obj = record.getEndereco().data;
            var enderecos = '';
            enderecos = enderecos + obj.logradouro;
            enderecos = enderecos + ' ' + obj.endereco;
            enderecos = enderecos + ' ' + obj.numero;
            enderecos = enderecos + ' - ' + obj.cidade;
            return enderecos;
        }
    }
             
             ],
    height: 200,
    width: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css"
/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all.js'></script>
```

Comment: Vou responder por partes, por causa do tamanho vou acrescentando nessa resposta. Ou você prefere aguardar eu responder tudo de uma só vez?

Comment: Opa, fique a vontade, eu vou acompanhando suas edições!

Comment: Só um detalhe: eu generalizei o título da questão para grids e forms porém, como perguntei no meio da questão, meu maior problema é em como criar o vínculo entre o model com associações e um formulário, desde preencher os campos do form (edição) até clicar em "salvar" no form e eu resgatar os valores digitados pelo usuário dentro do meu model.